# ShowDialog method without blocking other windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I write program for sorting music.
For saving your time and better understanding of my issue,i will write short.
Here is my problem.
I have some cycle in MainMethod.
Here is cycle

```
  private void OkButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)//when i press ok button in Main window i run cycle
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            //do something.

            Window window1 = new Window();
            window1.ShowDialog();//if i use ShowDialog it blocks MainWindow.
           //window1.Show();if i use Show it continues creating new windows. in cycle.
        }
    }
```

So i need to delay executing MainWindow OkButton method,while window1 is opened.Without blocking Main Window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `async`/`await` and a semaphore along these lines:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var signal = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var window = new Window();
        window.Closed += (s, _) => signal.Release();

        window.Show();

        await signal.WaitAsync();
    }
}
```